# Excel 2013 Wildcards on specific range and Sumif

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013, wildcards, range

I'm trying to use a wildcard limited to a specific range within a Sumif function.

Example:

I got these codes:

```
ABC-1
ABC-2
ABC-3
ABC-4
ABC-5
ABC-6
```

And I want to SUMIF from ABC-3 to ABC-5.

I found out that formerly I should use ABC-[!3-5] but on Excel 2013 it's not working.

Any help would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
=SUM(SUMIF(A:A,"ABC-" & {3,4,5},B:B))
```

This will perform three SUMIFS and sum the results.

[image]

Edit:

To be a little more dynamic, you could put the start and end points in two cells then use this array formula to get your answer:

```
=SUM(SUMIF(A:A,"ABC-" & ROW(INDIRECT($D$1 & ":" & $D$2)),B:B))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting Edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

Comment: This works great for this specific situation. Is there a more generic way to do it? If I had diferent series of codes requiring the use of the former wildcard format "ABC-[!3-5]".

Comment: @VicenteGre see edit.

Comment: Although, is there a way to also refer the "ABC-" part to another cell?

Comment: @VicenteGre sure just replace `"ABC-"` with your cell reference.

Comment: Hello, Scott.  It’s a good answer, and I can see that it works, but, as a casual reader, all I can tell is that you’ve produced a result that is *probably* the sum of three of the cells from Column `B`.  For both debugging and presentation purposes, I recommend setting Column `B`, not to multiple copies of the same value, but to 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, … (or, if you prefer, 1, 2, 4, 10, 20, 40, 100, …) so it’s easy to tell, uniquely and unambiguously, which Column `B` cells are being added.